# Поменять цвет курсора

Tags: c#, asp.net, цвета, .net, курсор

Добрый день!
Есть задание: написать консольное приложение в котором курсор будет зеленого цвета во всю величину символа и мигать, печатать он должен текст также синего цвета.
Просьба код не писать, а объяснить на словах. Какой использовать класс и какие методы. Так сказать чтобы сам сделал.
P.S. лажу в классе `Cursor` но пока нечего толкового не вижу

Comment: VladD: Сдал все нормально, так что уже не надо доделывать. Еще раз спасибо за помощь, очень выручили. 
У меня к вам другой вопрос. Знаете ли вы литературу, или вообще что нибуть посоветуете, как продвигать софт через торренты, и вообще через загрущики софта. Тоесть будет программа нужно ее распространнить в бесплатных файло обменниках, так вот нужнга инфа как ето делать, может подскажете?

Comment: @slavkan777: Вообще ничего не знаю по теме, сорри.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу цвета текста, вам достаточно использовать [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx).

Размер курсора устанавливается функцией [`Console.CursorSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorsize.aspx) (аргумент от 1 до 100, так что если вам надо полный размер, выбирайте 100).

Теперь по поводу цвета самого курсора. В C# я не нашёл встроенной функции, которая устанавливает цвет курсора. Он устанавливается неявно, как *дополнительный цвет* к цвету фона ([`Console.BackgroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx)). Это значит, вам нужно подобрать такой цвет фона, чтобы курсор вышел зелёным. У меня такое получилось для `BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta`, но вы попробуйте и другие цвета.

Не забудьте вызвать [`Console.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear.aspx), чтобы залить фоновым цветом всю консоль.

Недостаток такого решения — невозможность поменять цвет фона на менее отвратительный. Ну что ж, какое задание, такое и решение. Не забудьте растолковать преподавателю тонкость с цветом фона и курсора.

Comment: VladD - огромное спасибо, сейчас буду експерементировать. Но боюсь еще появяться вопросы)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Будут вопросы — задавайте! :)

Comment: Проблема все равно с курсором, он не зеленый((( и не совсем понятно где в коде вызывать  Console.Clear
 
Код:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Task26_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleColor value = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = value;
            Console.CursorSize = 100;

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}

Comment: Console.Clear вызвать перед Console.ReadLine();

Comment: если в лоб, то все же придется маргенту оставить

Comment: А как по другому можно? есть варианты?

Comment: @slavkan777: А почему по-другому? Что не так с этим вариантом?

Comment: Больно уш екцентричный цвет.
Могут не понять)))
Хотя все строго т.з. и ето правильно, но всетаки нуждно подумать есть ли ещем варианты))))

Comment: Да, цвет диковатый :-) Я глянул в WinAPI, там есть [`SetConsoleCursorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686019.aspx), но в ней тоже можно поменять лишь [размер](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682068.aspx). Вы можете в принципе отключить нафиг настоящий курсор и рисовать свой, меняя цвет фона символа под курсором на таймере. Но это геморройно, хотя не так уж и сложно.